# WhatsApp Webhook - Location

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Does anybody know how to respond to an incoming whatsapp message with a location (persistantAction) from a webhook? I could not find anything regarding persistentAction or location on the messaging schema,  the only way I could do it was sending an independent message but not using the response on the webook.  It seems possible to return a collection of messages (with or without media) but not a location.

Comment: Here you can find the documentation for that.  I did that last week with no issue, you have to complete and follow the instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks

Comment: the question is not how to setup a webhook.  It's when using a webhook hosted on twilio how send a response on their infrastructure with a Location.

Answer (score 0):

When [Twilio sends the webhook for a message with a location](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/message-features#receive-inbound-location-messages) it sends 4 extra parameters: `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Address` and `Label`.

I wrote a blog post which discusses [how to handle WhatsApp location messages in Ruby](https://www.twilio.com/blog/location-aware-whatsapp-bot-ruby-sinatra-twilio) and my colleague wrote one that [handled WhatsApp location messages in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/glorious-food) which may help.

---

To respond to a WhatsApp message with a location you cannot do so with TwiML. Instead, you need to send a message using the REST API, passing the latitude and longitude coordinates as the `PersistentAction` parameter in this format: `geo:{latitude},{longitude}` or with an optional label: `geo:{latitude},{longitude}|{label}`.

In Node.js using the Twilio library this looks like:

```js
client.messages
      .create({
         messagingServiceSid: 'MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
         body: 'This is one of the Twilio office locations',
         persistentAction: ['geo:37.787890,-122.391664|375 Beale St'],
         to: 'whatsapp:+15005550006'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

See the [documentation on sending location messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/message-features#send-outbound-location-messages) for more detail.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough,  the point is not receiving a location but adding a location on the response from the webhook.  All the samples you provided were about receiving a location.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can't use TwiML to respond with a location message, you need to use the REST API. I've updated my answer.